# Windows Server 2008 r2 - too much RAM when idle

Tags: memory, vmware, windows-server-2008-r2

My hosting company has recently upgraded my VPS to 6 CPU units and 4GB of RAM. It't running Windows Server 2008 r2 x64.

After the upgrade I can notice that 50%-75% (2GB-3GB) of RAM is being used even when all the applications are closed and right after I boot the machine.

When I check what is using RAM with RamMap, it shows Driver Locked that uses almost 3GB of RAM.

I've made a research and found out that usually it happens to a virtual machines on VMWare and is related to VMWare tools, memory settings in VMWare and Virtio Balloon Service.

But when it comes to VPS run by a hosting company, what can it depend on?

They suggested me to try disabling Virtio Balloon Service but when I tried nothing has changed.

The software that I usually run is a proxy software Proxy Multiply and a twitter software Tweet Attacks.

But as I mentioned before a huge RAM usage happens even when all the software is closed and just after reboot.

Does anyone have any clue what that Driver Locked can actually mean and how to release the memory?

Thanks

RamMap - Driver Locked: http://s1.postimg.org/gf4dfvepr/Ram_Map.jpg

Comment: Unused memory is useless memory.  When your applicationr requires more memory Windows will free up memory from other tasks.  Unless you pay for each MB/sec in your memory you are trying to battle normal operating procedures.

Answer (score 0):

Seems I have solved the problem by disabling the Virtio Balloon driver and rebooting the machine. (Disabling just balloon service was not enough.)

Now the memory usage is aroung 1GB with all the software running. That is awesome.

Comment: Yes, although not so awesome for your VPS provider. Cheap prices are only possible with overcommitting resources.

Answer (score -1):

The short answer is your hosting provider controls the balloon.  VMWare uses the balloon to manage memory of the guest OSes.  We had a similar issue and the hosting provider had to take steps to free the RAM for our VMs.

More info on how the ballon works:  http://rwmj.wordpress.com/2010/07/17/virtio-balloon/

What VMWare has to say about it:  http://performancebydesign.blogspot.com/2013/07/virtual-memory-management-in-vmware.html

Comment: please the long answer here, and don't use links to explain your answer, links can die, your answer here will never die

Comment: The balloon driver is a way to give or take RAM from a guest operating system.  The balloon represents memory you paid for but aren't using at the moment. VMWare instructs the balloon to change size when it begins to encounter contention for memory from other guests.  The balloon should be invisible to the guest OS; the guest should feel free to use all the memory it believes it has.

Comment: Thank you for your answer wrk2bike. I contacted my hosting company in regard to the problem and here's what they replied: "We give 1:1 memory in all VPS. Right now real server have 10GB free + swap avaible" The thing that worry me most of all is that locked driver in RamMap that uses 75% of the memory. How can I find out what exactly is that driver?

Comment: Glad to see you resolved the issue.